# Reading from text and create random profile for chrome not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, notepad

Why is this only launching same chrome profile when it prints out random chrome profiles?

I have a text file with:

```
'--profile-directory=Person 1
'--profile-directory=Person 2
```

It reads a random line and loads it into Chrome. Why is it not working?

I've included Example 1 which is what I'm having trouble with:

Example 1:

```
import random
import random
lines = open('C:\\Users\\Hoxton\\Pictures\\1\\ad.txt').read().splitlines()
myline =random.choice(lines)
print(myline)


Profiles = []

for x in (myline):
    indexes = [index for index in range(len(myline))]
    shuffle(indexes)
    dataDir = "--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Hoxton\\AppData\\Local\Google\\Chrome\\User Data"
    chrome_options1 = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options1.add_argument(dataDir)
    chrome_options1.add_argument(x)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options1)
    driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

It should be noted that the following works perfectly.
Example 2

```
foo = ['--profile-directory=Person 1', '--profile-directory=Person 2', '--profile-directory=Person 3', '--profile-directory=Person 4', '--profile-directory=Person 5']
from random import randrange
random_index = randrange(0,len(foo))
print(foo[random_index])

Profiles = []

for x in [foo[random_index]]:
    indexes = [index for index in range(len(foo[random_index]))]
    shuffle(indexes)
    dataDir = "--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Hoxton\\AppData\\Local\Google\\Chrome\\User Data"
    chrome_options1 = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options1.add_argument(dataDir)
    chrome_options1.add_argument(x)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options1)
    driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Can someone help me get example one working for reading from a notepad?  I am unable to see what I am doing in the first example.

Comment: try changing `for x in (myline)` to `for x in (myline,)` or to even better `for x in [myline]` or if you want much much better solution, then remove the for loop if you have not more than one option in a single line of the txt file

Comment: @tkhurana96 Changing it to: for x in [myline] did not work for me.   I'm not sure what you mean by removing for loop as it would always get person 2

Comment: just to check whether what it does is what you want, try adding `print(x)` as the very first statement in your `for x in (myline)` loop, just do this for debugging purposes, and let me know whether the output that you got is what you intended to do, because your 2nd example iterates over a list of strings, and your 1st example iterates over characters in a string :)

Comment: @tkhurana96 Uh... I see.  I get: '--profile-directory=Person 1'.  But for printing print(x) I get '. But doesn't it read from myline anyway which is always different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In example 1. You are iterating over a string. In example 2, you are iterating over a list.

Try this example which may demonstrate the issue:

```
import random
lines = ['--profile-directory=Person 1', '--profile-directory=Person 2', '--profile-directory=Person 3', '--profile-directory=Person 4', '--profile-directory=Person 5']
# This returns a string.
myline = random.choice(lines)

# iterate over a string (x = string char).
for x in (myline):
    print(x)

# iterate over a tuple (x = tuple item).
for x in (myline,):
    print(x)
```

The above uses a string and a tuple though the tuple is similar to the list used in example 2 with using `[]` which encloses `foo[random_index]` to become the list `[foo[random_index]]`.

Edit:

As per request from comment, a possible solution as I do not have the environment for actual testing.

```
import random
from selenium import webdriver

with open('C:\\Users\\Hoxton\\Pictures\\1\\ad.txt') as r:
    lines = r.readlines()

myline = random.choice(lines).strip()
# Add string to a list.
if type(myline) is str:
    myline = [myline]
# Display myline
print(repr(myline))

Profiles = [] # obsolete?
dataDir = "--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Hoxton\\AppData\\Local\Google\\Chrome\\User Data"

for x in myline:
    indexes = [index for index in range(len(myline))]
    random.shuffle(indexes)
    chrome_options1 = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options1.add_argument(dataDir)
    chrome_options1.add_argument(x)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options1)
    driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Edit: Added type str check for myline in case you change from a random string to a sequence sequence type for some reason.

Comment: Can you show an example using a simple text file and get it to load a different chrome?

Comment: This tends to create the same profile each time.  This is very strange behaviour.  Nevermind, that works as expected.  Cheers :D

Comment: The only one problem I found is it won't navigate to a page when using this method.

Comment: @Tmaker . I am not sure about the navigation. Usage of `driver.get` looks ok as to viewing examples at  https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started .

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.  I forgot to clarify.  I accepted your solution.  Remove: chrome_options1.add_argument(dataDir)
    chrome_options1.add_argument(x) and it will work as expected.  Those lines stop the job working correctly.

Comment: @Tmaker Thanks for the info. Those args may work if file has `'Person 1\nPerson 2'` and `use chrome_options1.add_argument(dataDir + '\\' + x)` and chrome_options1.add_argument('--profile-directory' + x). If it works, great, if not, worth a try.

Comment: Correction for last comment: `chrome_options1.add_argument('--profile-directory=' + x)`. Added missing `=`.